# Google libraries loading issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, libraries

I developped a small app about the increase of airbnb in Paris http://www.simonblum.me/post/hacks/airbnb-paris

Sometimes JSON is not loaded due to an error (this.set is undefined Line 42)
When this error occurs a file is missing : visualization_impl.js . This file is loaded with the Gmaps library : visualization.

I don't know what happend but sometimes this library is not loaded or initMap is executed before this file is loaded.

How to solve my problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Post your code please!

Answer (score 0):

Put your library import code (like `<script src="/js/airbnb.js"></script>`) to the `<head>` tag.